# Reinitialise the coordinate by using setter in Javascripts

Tags: javascript, oop, getter, setter

I am new to OOP and just learning now.  I want to reinitialise the default location of a circle by using the codes below:

```js
function Circle(radius) {
  
  this.radius = radius;
  
  let defaultLocation = {
    x: 0,
    y: 0
  };

  this.getDefaultLocation = function(a, b) {
    return defaultLocation
  };
  
  Object.defineProperty(this, 'defaultLocation', {
    get: function(a, b) {
      return defaultLocation;
    },
    set: function(a, b) {
      defaultLocation = {
        x: a,
        y: b
      };
    }
  });

}

const circle = new Circle(10);

circle.defaultLocation = {
  x: 5,
  y: 6
};
```

However, i check in the chrome browser console, the result is:

```
x: {x: 5, y: 6}
y: undefined
```

Could you tell me where i done wrong and how to correct it?
Thanks.

Comment: `set` cannot take two parameters, since it takes its value from the assignment. And assignment only does one value at a time.

Comment: More generally, I'd expect this to use `class` syntax rather than a constructor function and a `Object.defineProperty()` . There is no reason to reinvent this by hand.

Comment: @VLAZ, thanks for your comment, this is an exercise only, is possible to achieve by using setter and how? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't pass two variables to `set`, but you can pass an object (or an array).

```
class Circle {

  get defaultLocation() {
    return this._defaultLocation
  }
  
  set defaultLocation(loc) {
    this._defaultLocation = loc
  }
  
  constructor(radius) {
    this.radius = radius;
    this._defaultLocation = {
        x: 0,
        y: 0
    };
  }

}

const circle = new Circle(10);

circle.defaultLocation = {
  x: 5,
  y: 6
};
```

Comment: Many thanks, you use class and there is no function of Object.definedProperty, is this the advantage to using Class in this case, not to use Closure? Is there a way that using constructor also can do that? And you have helped to solve my question, and many thanks.

Comment: One more question, why you use this._, not directly this.defualtLocation....? Thanks.

Comment: If you put `this.something = ...` in a `class` it's the same as using `Object.definedProperty`. The `class` keyword provides you with a shorter way of writing what you did in your question.  I use the `_` because the `set defaultLocation` cannot have the same name as the variable that you are actually setting. This is a way to "protect" the inner variable. The `_` reminds you that it should only be used inside the class. (Another way to do that is by using `#` ).

Comment: I am just a beginner to OOPs, Many Thanks!